# Get mouse events from floating picture-in-picture window

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, picture-in-picture

I have a canvas that is being rendered onto a video via [`video.srcObject = canvas.captureSteam()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream)

That video is then made the active picture-in-picture element using [`video.requestPictureInPicture()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/requestPictureInPicture)

I would like to add some interactivity to the floating window (for example, a clickable button rendered in the canvas).

Is there a way to get mouse events on the floating window? All I really need is the mouse position and mouse button down/up.

I have tried using `addEventListener` on the `PictureInPictureWindow` that is returned from `requestPictureInPicture` but it seems like the only event that it is able to pass is [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PictureInPictureWindow#events)

Comment: There was some discussion in https://github.com/w3c/picture-in-picture/issues/113#issuecomment-457097419 about adding interactive PiP but it brings soem security threats and wouldn't work on mobile, so it's unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for my use case, this was for a video conferencing app. I only needed audio and video mute and a hangup button; it turns out that these are implemented in the `MediaSession` API.

Adding the following made audio mute/unmute, video mute/unmute, and a hangup button show on the picture-in-picture window on hover:

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('togglemicrophone', toggleAudioMuted);
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('togglecamera', toggleVideoMuted);
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('hangup', hangup);
```

`navigator.mediaSession.setMicrophoneActive` and `navigator.mediaSession.setCameraActive` could also be used to sync the muted/unmuted status with the picture-in-picture window.

More details can be found here:
https://w3c.github.io/mediasession/#the-mediasession-interface

And here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession